# download image from wamp server and save in my folder loacated in same using php

Tags: php, image, download, save, directory

hello friends i want to save image from my wamp server to my specific wamp project folder  i have used below code ,this code show me the dialog to save image but i want to call image from wamp server and save it in my folder

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    $imageUrl = "http://ip/demo/images/itemimage/Platters.png";
    $filename = realpath(dirname("http://ip/demo/images/itemimage/Platters.png"))."/image1.png";
    $handle = file_get_contents($imageUrl); 
    file_put_contents($filename, $handle);

?>
```

this code do not download image automatically to my folde can any one help me ?
i got ths error  with above code

[image]

Comment: In same server?? Why not just use `copy` ?

Comment: for test i m using same server then will be from server to my device ,thenafter i'll be changing  download loaction

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_get_contents($imageUrl));` output? Remember to remove the `header` for debugging.

Comment: you should use the local file path not an url

Comment: $handle = file_get_contents($imageUrl);echo($handle) gives me my image in echo just this image i want to save in my folder i hv edited question pls check

Comment: @Dagon i have tried that but not working

Comment: your not making it easy to help you.

Comment: @Dagon as u said local file path works now what if i what to save on server?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you do two things on your script. You set the image to deliver the image over the php script.

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    echo file_get_contents("http://ip/demo/images/itemimage/Platters.png");
?>
```

Then you should fetch the image and send the image with echo to the user.

When you want to save the image then you need only fetch the image with **file_get_contents** and put them to your harddrive what you do at the moment.

I think in your example the **echo missing** this is why you get the error. You set the content type of the site but you don't deliver any png data.

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    $handle = file_get_contents("http://ip/demo/images/itemimage/Platters.png"); 
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).md5(time()), $handle);
    echo $handle;
?>
```

**Edit:** Try something like this. Then he should save the image in the same path.

Comment: CO: file_get_contents is not best practices to get content from another server, because the data would put down into the memory wholly. But in this case it may to be used.

Comment: echo the image information. This error comes because you don't send any data to the browser.

Comment: ok i have done that but i am not able to download my image to my folder which is located on the server (same server),if i give local path to any  drive it works fine

Answer (score -1):

One way:

```
exec("wget http://ip/demo/images/itemimage/Platters.png /tmp/demo/images/itemimage/Platters.png");
```

Comment: Also, suppose you have got some error, that you can see, because use image-header. Check your log file